# Simple workflow for projecting image onto mesh

Tags: python, image

I have a geometry that I have acquired via photogrammetry (for now - better methods might come later) that looks like this:

[image]

and a background image that I have positioned and resized like this:

[image]

and here are the two together:

[image]

Is there a *simple* way to project the image onto the mesh?

By simple I mean one of:

- a 2-3 steps workflow
- a python-automated workflow (and if so please help with this)

in the end this should be a step that is repeated 4-6 times, one for each view (top, bottom etc.) in a design process (which means the views might be custom-drawn, and the geometry not acquired via photogrammetry).

I've gone htrough pretty much every answer [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=project%20image%20onto%20mesh%20blender%20site%3Ablender.stackexchange.com&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu-sn&hs=Zx4&sca_esv=558130159&channel=fs&ei=ZIPfZMPhIcXUxc8P0J-3yAE&ved=0ahUKEwjDo5TVuOaAAxVFavEDHdDPDRkQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=project%20image%20onto%20mesh%20blender%20site%3Ablender.stackexchange.com&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiPnByb2plY3QgaW1hZ2Ugb250byBtZXNoIGJsZW5kZXIgc2l0ZTpibGVuZGVyLnN0YWNrZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tSO85ULcCWK43cAF4AZABAJgBlAGgAekTqgEEMjUuNrgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgYQABgWGB7CAggQABiKBRiGA8ICBRAhGKABwgIIECEYFhgeGB3CAgQQIRgV4gMEGAAgQYgGAZAGCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) but I don't think any of the answers qualify as *simple* workflows.

Comment: Something like Edit mode > u > unwrap > project from view (bounds) would produce UVs that give you this result. But that knid of method usually requires multiple projections from different viewpoints  to multiple UVs and a form of procedural or manual blending between the projections so that you don't see the edges of each projections.

Comment: @L0Lock - that seems to work beautifully, thank you very much. Would you care to elaborate on the topic of multiple projections and blending between them?

Comment: You might find the bench scene of the latest Captain Dissilusion video very informative for your workflow. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHx4xVhfS3w It's tedious, but I think that's what you want. The part you want starts around 4:30

Comment: It depends a lot on the mesh and the textures you actually have so you have to adapt all the time. I haven't done this in years, it's an old method of texturing, so on my part I will leave it at that.